# What is the most efficient way to store large arrays of floating point data in mysql for access through django?

Tags: mysql, django, math, binary, floating-point

I am a mechanical engineer that has picked up functional bits of programming, but I am lacking thorough insight. I searched for answer to this question but couldn't find anything.

I am making a django web application to search and filter test data stored in a mysql database. My question regards the best method to store the data?

The data are large arrays of numbers that might be 5,000 values in length and each number looks like this 0.000012341245345. These are measurements taken off of accelerometers. I don't know how accurate all those significant figures are, but I want to store everything as I get it.

**The Question:** What Django field type would I use? This field does not have to be searchable. I just want to pull the data when called.

Everything in django seems to be unicode. I have been reading up on packing numbers as double precision binary numbers. But if I store a unicode string like this '\x1e1\x1d6\xea\X00a2' will that really help me keep the memory requirements down?

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you only plan to read the data, or do you want to read/write?

Comment: After entering the data, the only need would be to read.

Comment: Are you entering the data through the Django interface or does the web interface serve only to display data? If you already populate your data elsewhere and only want to show it through the web, then this problem becomes very easy. If you want to enter values through the web interface, this is slightly harder.

Comment: @Nick I will write another python script elsewhere to automate the data entery, but I have been using the django api. I have created a Django model that has the following fields: signal-a fk referance to a signal_log table, start_time, dt- time increment, title-for reference so you can be certain the result matches your query, and data. So I would use something like this to enter the data: `Time_Signals(signal=,start_time=,dt=,title=,data=)`. How would I define the _data_ filed in django? I was thinking something like this: `data = models.CharField(max_length=20000)`? Does len need to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of snippets on django snippets that will help you do what you want.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1669/

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1597/

Comment: Thanks, that is help. I'll look into these suggestions.

Comment: Rory, I put that django snippet to use (1669). It works well. I am able to store numpy arrays without having to do a value by value string conversion to put the contents of the array into a unicode django text field. In case anyone finds this useful, here is the method I use to recover the array from the base64 data after pulling it from the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485790/numpy-array-to-base64-and-back-to-numpy-array-python

Answer (score 2):

Most modern systems have more than enough memory so going to great lengths to save a few bytes here and there aren't worth the complexity and investment in development.

A database `double` is more than adequate for such a value.  Clearly, there are way more significant digits than a transducer can accurately provide.  If there is some sort of chain-of-custody of evidence, then store the value as a string.  It can be converted to a *float* or *double* on-the-fly if needed for a calculation.

Comment: Yes memory is abundant these days, but how would you recommend storing these long strings of numbers? In django do I need to set a max_length on each field type?

Comment: Django typically is configured with a standard SQL database backend.  Probably `varchar(30)` is adequate for any value like that if you go with a string.  Otherwise use `double`.

Comment: I want to store the entire time history that could have up to 24,000 values in it. Most contain about 2000 values. So as a string a typical array has a length greater than 6000 characters. How would you set this field? If you are familiar with Django, I was considering the TextField (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#textfield)

Comment: @sequoia:  24k samples of 5k values is 120 million values.  Stored as 30 bytes each, that is only 3.6 gigabyte.  A $10 memory card can easily hold that.   Stored as 8-byte doubles, it is less than one gigabyte.  What's the big deal?

Comment: whoa, sorry, just I'd try to be a little more efficient