# Numpy Array to base64 and back to Numpy Array - Python

Tags: python, django, arrays, numpy, base64

I am now trying to figure out how I can recover a numpy array from base64 data. This question and answer suggest it is possible: [Reading numpy arrays outside of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725602/reading-numpy-arrays-outside-of-python) but an example is not given.

Using the code below as an example, how can I get a Numpy array from the base64 data if I know the dtype and the shape of the array?

```
import base64
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(25, dtype=np.float64)
s = base64.b64encode(t)
r = base64.decodestring(s)
q = ?????
```

I want a python statement to set q as a numpy array of dtype float64 so the result is an array identical to t. This is what the arrays encoded and decoded look like:

```
>>> t = np.arange(25,dtype=np.float64)
>>> t
array([  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,
    11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,
    22.,  23.,  24.])
>>> s=base64.b64encode(t)
>>> s
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAACEAAAAAAAAAQQAAAAAAAABRAAAAAAAAAGEAAAAAAAAAcQAAAAAAAACBAAAAAAAAAIkAAAAAAAAAkQAAAAAAAACZAAAAAAAAAKEAAAAAAAAAqQAAAAAAAACxAAAAAAAAALkAAAAAAAAAwQAAAAAAAADFAAAAAAAAAMkAAAAAAAAAzQAAAAAAAADRAAAAAAAAANUAAAAAAAAA2QAAAAAAAADdAAAAAAAAAOEA='
>>> r = base64.decodestring(s)
>>> r
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 @\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00$@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00&@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00,@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x002@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x003@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x004@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x005@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x007@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008@'
>>> q = np.array( ????
```

The reason I am asking is because I am working on a project where I would like to store a lot of Numpy arrays in a MySQL database in an app powered by django.

Using this django snippet I can store base64 data in a textfield: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1669/

I want to write the arrays to the database as base64 instead of converting the arrays to a string of unicode.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
import base64
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(25, dtype=np.float64)
s = base64.b64encode(t)
r = base64.decodebytes(s)
q = np.frombuffer(r, dtype=np.float64)

print(np.allclose(q, t))
# True
```

Comment: I'll also add that I have made this work for multidimensional arrays by applying the q = np.reshape(q,(m,n)), where m and n where the original dimensions of the t array.

Comment: The multidimensional array handling caught me off guard -- b64encode was returning a result for multidimensional arrays, but those arrays did not contain the "inner" arrays... scary. Thanks for the great pointers!

Comment: just coming back here to add another warning (since I've just been bitten by this). watch out if your numpy dtype is not float64. for instance, if your source numpy array contains ints only, the code above will happily encode and decode it. but the end result will be completely wrong, and there will be no warnings (I understand that I should have been careful, but silent errors happen & are annoying/dangerous). :-/

Comment: The "decoding" dtype used in `q = np.frombuffer(r, dtype=np.int32)` must match the dtype of the original array, `t = np.arange(25, dtype=np.int32)` which is passed to `base64.b64encode(t)`. There is nothing special about `float64` per se.

Answer (score 6):

The code below will encode it as base64.  It will handle numpy arrays of any type/size without needing to remember what it was.  It will also handle other arbitrary objects that can be pickled.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import codecs

obj = np.random.normal(size=(10, 10))
obj_base64string = codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), "base64").decode('latin1')
obj_reconstituted = pickle.loads(codecs.decode(obj_base64string.encode('latin1'), "base64"))
```

You can remove .decode('latin1') and .encode('latin1') if you just want the raw bytes.

Comment: Unless there's some reason I'm not seeing, I like this answer better, thank you.

Comment: The main benefit of this over the accepted answer is you don't need to convert it into the right type after decoding.  You decode it and it is the type that is was.  Perfect for use cases like web APIs where you have no control over the other end of the software.

Comment: One drawback is that you are bound to unpickle it on the other side (exclusively from python), so it's not a format you can interchange with other techonologies. I had to move to another approach since the receiving part was not python.