# From JPG to b64encode to cv2.imread()

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

For a program I am writing, I am transferring an image from one computer - using base64.b64encode(f.read(image)) - and trying to read it in the receiving script without saving it to hard drive (in an effort to minimize process time). I'm having a hard time figuring out how to read the image into OpenCV without saving it locally.

Here is what my code for sending the image looks like:

```
f = open(image.jpg)
sendthis = f.read()
f.close()
databeingsent = base64.b64encode(sendthis)
client.publish('/image',databeingsent,0) 
# this is an MQTT publish, details for SO shouldn't be relevant
```

Meanwhile, here is the code receiving it. (This is in an on_message function, since I'm using MQTT for the transfer.)

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg): # msg.payload is incoming data
    img = base64.b64decode(msg.payload)
    source = cv2.imread(img)
    cv2.imshow("image", source)
```

After the message decodes, I have the error:
"TypeError: Your input type is not a numpy array".

I've done some searching, and I can't seem to find a relevant solution - some exist regarding converting from text files to numpy using b64, but none really relate to using an image and immediately reading that decoded data into OpenCV without the intermediary step of saving it to the harddrive (using the inverse process used to read the file in the "send" script).

I'm still pretty new to Python and OpenCV, so if there's a better encoding method to send the image - whatever solves the problem. How the image is sent is irrelevant, so long as I can read it in on the receiving end without saving it as a .jpg to disk.

Thanks!

Comment: use `imdecode` instead of `imread`

Comment: "buf is not a numpy array, neither a scalar" tried passing the b64decode step here, still got this error. so, still asking for a numpy array

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6485943/5008845) helps. Then you need imdecode, because imread loads an image from disk.

Comment: I had seen that before, and it didn't help. They are trying to do something pretty different and I am not experienced enough to draw from it a meaningful example/translation.

Comment: I was referring to `np.frombuffer` to get the numpy array from your decoded `img`. Then you can pass the numpy array to imdecode

Comment: was just trying that to no avail

Comment: probably `np.array(list(img), dtype=np.uint8)` or `np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)` will do the trick. But I don't know python. My advice is just that you need imdecode. How to get parameters type right it's up to you :D

Comment: Or just wait for a Python guy to rescue us here :D

Comment: Well,  the second one- fromstring- worked. So, yay! Thanks. If you write it below as an answer, I will accept that so you get credit for it.

While I'm now getting another error in a separate layer of the program, this did resolve the issue I asked about. this new error should be easy to figure out, anyways. Thanks!!

FYI - this is the new, working block:

  img = base64.b64decode(msg.payload);     

  npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8);     

  source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get a numpy array from you decoded data using:

```
import numpy as np
...
img = base64.b64decode(msg.payload)
npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then you need [imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imdecode) to read the image from a buffer in memory. [imread](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imread) is meant to load an image from a file.

So:

```
import numpy as np
...
def on_message(client, userdata, msg): # msg.payload is incoming data
    img = base64.b64decode(msg.payload); 
    npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8); 
    source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
```

Comment: you may want to delete the very last line with cv2.imshow - it locks up when I do that. but that wasn't something critical to the program - it was just an intermediary step I inserted to make the code in the original question make more sense. the important point is that everything prior to that resolves the issue I was having, and now everything is fiiiiine! Thanks!

Comment: ok thanks. You probably need cv2.waitKey(1) to see the _imshowed_ image and avoid blocking.

Comment: yeah, I had that and it still locked up. the part of my program that interacts with this does essentially the same thing, and that's the 'new issue' I alluded to in the question's comments. I think it's just a data type issue and should be easy to resolve. thanks again! :D

Comment: hi @Miki and @godfreap, I would like to ask... in this code above: ```source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)``` 1 is a flag... what is the meaning value of 1 here ? how if I didn't set the flag=1, is there any difference ?

Comment: @uyhaW yes it's a flag. Read [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80)

Comment: Sparing a precious minute to anyone who's wondering what that `1` is doing in `source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)`: it's the equivalent of `cv2.IMREAD_COLOR`, which does: `If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.`

Answer (score 4):

From the OpenCV [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=read) we can see that:

**imread** : Loads an image from a file.

**imdecode** : Reads an image from a buffer in memory.

Seem a better way to do what you want.