# Python: Alternate way to covert from base64 string to opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to convert this string in base64 (http://pastebin.com/uz4ta0RL) to something usable by OpenCV.
Currently I am using this code (img_temp is the string) to use the OpenCV functions by converting it to a temp image(imagetosave.jpg) then loading the temp image with cv2.imread.

```
    fh = open('imagetosave.jpg','wb')
    fh.write(img_temp.decode('base64'))
    fh.close()

    img = cv2.imread('imagetosave.jpg',-1)
```

Though this method works, I would like to be able to use the OpenCV functions without using a temp image.
Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33522724/5008845

Comment: thanks, i thought i had already tried that but i guess not!

Answer (score 0):

To convert string from base64 to normal you can use

```
import base64
base64.b64decode("TGlrZSB0aGF0Cg==")
```

but it itsn't unclear if is what you need.

Comment: So I'd like to be able to use the string from base64 to a format useable by OpenCV without having to write over imagetosave.jpg since its acting as a temporary image.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your decoded string to a list of integers, which you can then pass to the `imdecode` function:

```
img_array = map(int, img_temp.decode('base64'))
img = cv2.imdecode(img_array, -1)
```

Comment: I'm getting: invalid literal for int() with base 10