# Python send opencv img with socket.io to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, opencv, socket.io-1.0

Im testing with this piece of code to send opencv img from python to nodejs with socket.io but its not working can anyone help me with?

Python

```
from socketio import Client
from cv2 import imread, imencode
import base64

socket = Client( )

@socket.on( 'connect' )
def connect( ):
    print( 'connected to server' )
    img = imread( 'screenshot.png' )
    frame = imencode( '.png', img )[ 1 ]
    encoded = base64.b64encode( frame ) 
    socket.emit( 'img', encoded )

@socket.on( 'disconnect' )
def disconnect( ):
    print( 'disconnected from server' )

socket.connect( 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' )
socket.wait( )
```

Nodejs

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const app = express( )
const http = require( 'http' ).Server( app )
const socket = require( 'socket.io' )( http )
const path = require( 'path' )
const fs = require( 'fs' )
const cv = require( 'opencv4nodejs' );

app.get( '/', ( req, res ) => {
    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/index.html' ) )
} )

socket.on( 'connect', ( player ) => {
    console.log( 'Connected: '+ player.id )

    player.on( 'img', ( encoded ) => {
        var buffer = Buffer.from( encoded, 'base64' )
        var image = cv.imdecode( buffer, cv.IMREAD_COLOR )
        cv.imwrite( 'img.png', image )
    } )

    player.on( 'disconnect', ( player ) => {
        console.log( 'Disconnected: '+ player.id )
    } )
} )

http.listen( 3000, ( ) => {
    console.log( 'listening on *:3000' )
} )
```

Im getting this warnings/error in nodejs:

```
libpng warning: Image width is zero in IHDR
libpng warning: Image height is zero in IHDR
libpng error: Invalid IHDR data
```

Sorry for me bad english, and thanks by the way.

Comment: this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928205/python-opencv-image-to-byte-string-for-json-transfer

Answer (score 1):

I deduced it in another way.. it should decode with utf-8 the base64 string.

```
socket.emit( 'img', encoded.decode( 'utf-8' ) )
```