# Post image to Django REST API

Tags: python, django, numpy, post, encoding

I have a Django project that receives an image, process it and return a response. I am writing a script to test my API, but the bytes that client sends is not the same that the server receives.

Client code:

```
# client.py
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(image_file)
data = {'image': img.tobytes(), 'shape': img.shape}
data = urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
req = Request(service_url, data)
response = urlopen(req)
print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Views code:

```
# service/app/views.py
import ast
import numpy as np
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def process_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Converts string to tuple
        shape = ast.literal_eval(request.POST.get('shape'))
        img_bytes = request.POST.get('image')
        # Reconstruct the image
        img = np.fromstring(img_bytes, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
        # Process image
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'Hello'})
```

When i run cliente code i get `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`. I did the following checks, with a 8x8 RGB image:

```
# client.py
>> print(img.shape)
(8, 8, 3)
>> print(img.dtype)
uint8
>> print(len(img.tobytes()))
192

# service/app/views.py
>> print(shape)
(8, 8, 3)
>> print(len(img_bytes))
187
```

The `shape` field is ok, but the `image` filed has different size. As the image is small, i printed the bytes from client and server, and i did not get the same. I think that this is an encoding problem.

I want to send image as bytes, because i think this is a compact way to send this kind of data. If anyone know a better approach to send image via HTTP, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the point of `literal_eval` here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `literal_eval` converts `shape` from string to tuple.

Comment: By no means as compact as you want, I have a rest service where I just base64 encode an image before posting, and decode it on the server.  I think your problem is likely putting the raw bytes in the JSON request. I don't think you can put raw bytes in JSON.  For example the byte for a quote character would close the value string.

Comment: Thanks @JohnMorris!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by John Morris's commentary, i found the answer to my question in [Numpy Array to base64 and back to Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485790/numpy-array-to-base64-and-back-to-numpy-array-python) post. If anyone has the same doubt, here is the solution:

Client code:

```
# client.py
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(image_file)
img_b64 = base64.b64encode(img)
data = {'image': img_b64, 'shape': img.shape}
data = urlencode(data).encode("utf-8")
req = Request(service_url, data)
response = urlopen(req)
print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Views code:

```
# service/app/views.py
import ast
import base64
import numpy as np
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def process_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shape = ast.literal_eval(request.POST.get('shape'))
        buffer = base64.b64decode(request.POST.get('image'))
        # Reconstruct the image
        img = np.frombuffer(buffer, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape)
        # Process image
        return JsonResponse({'result': 'Hello'})
```

Thank you all!