# Decode unknown encoding for numpy array

Tags: numpy, decode

Can anybody help me decode this?

{'py/object': 'numpy.ndarray',
'values': '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',
'shape': [61],
'dtype': 'float64',
'byteorder': '<'}

Many thanks - looked through several encode/decode functions and haven't had any luck yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485790/numpy-array-to-base64-and-back-to-numpy-array-python

Comment: Can you tell us something about the source.  It's a `dict`  with the `values` looking like a string, or bytestring.  While I can apply `frombuffer` to it, I get 72 floats, not 61, and they look pretty random.